# How to get the front camera in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to get the front camera with live view. I am able to get the back camera using:

```
var backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
```

But I can't seem to find how to get the front camera. How can I change the code above to use the front camera?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a working example from one of my projects to get the front camera. This is in objective-c but proven to work and easy enough to convert to swift.

```
NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices){

    if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront){

        captureDevice = device;
        break;
    }
}
```

And in Swift 3.2+:

```
if let videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
    var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice
    for device in videoDevices {
        if let device = device as? AVCaptureDevice {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front {
                captureDevice = device
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the swift code provided above, I used this code with Swift 2 iOS 9; I only had to remove the break as it gave me a compiling error. Great source here!

Answer (score 20):

In iOS 10.0 and later, you don't need to iterate through `AVCaptureDevice`.[`devices`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1386237-devices) (or [`devicesWithMediaType`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1390520-devices)) to find a camera by position. (In fact, both of those APIs are deprecated in iOS 10, and don't return the full set of available devices on iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 8 Plus, or iPhone X.)

If you just need to find a single device based on simple characteristics (like a front-facing camera that can shoot video), just use `AVCaptureDevice`.[`defaultDevice(withDeviceType:mediaType:position:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/2361508-defaultdevice). For example:

```
guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(
    withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera,
    mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
    position: .front)
    else { fatalError("no front camera. but don't all iOS 10 devices have them?")

// then use the device: captureSession.addInput(device) or whatever
```

Really that's all there is to it for most use cases.

---

There's also  [`AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevicediscoverysession) as a replacement for the old method of iterating through the `devices` array. However, most of the things you'd usually iterate through the `devices` array for can be found using the new [`defaultDevice(withDeviceType:mediaType:position:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/2361508-defaultdevice) method, so you might as well use that and write less code.

The cases where [`AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevicediscoverysession) is worth using are the less common, more complicated cases: say you want to find all the devices that support a certain frame rate, or use key-value observing to see when the set of available devices changes.

---

By the way, Apple also has [a guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/PhotoCaptureGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017511) to the iOS 10 / Swift 3 photo capture system and some [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) that both show current best practices for these APIs.

Answer (score 9):

```
guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.devices().filter({ $0.position == .Front })
    .first as? AVCaptureDevice else {
        fatalError("No front facing camera found")
}
```

If you're looking for a shorter solution although `.filter` followed by `.first` isn't the most efficient

Comment: Love the more compact code.  Is there any other type of device that might show as position = front though?  Wonder if it should be AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediatType(AVMediaTypeVideo).filter({ $0.position == .Front }).first as? AVCaptureDevice

Answer (score 8):

Latests is:

```
guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front) else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Explicitly demanding `builtInWideAngleCamera` seems prone to failure as future devices with different cameras come out... I am surprised Apple has made this so complex, I just iterate the old devices array and suppress the deprecated warning with CLANG.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4.1, iOS 10+ and **Xcode 9.3** replaces

```
if let cameraID = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.front)?.localizedName {
       //cameraID = "Front Camera"
}
```

with **AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession** implementation

```
if let cameraID = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.front).devices.first?.localizedName{
        //cameraID = "Front Camera"
}
```

Comment: Still not sure what to do with the cameraID. How can we achieve our goal to capture photo by using front camera

Answer (score 2):

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var frontDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
var frontInput: AVCaptureInput?

if let frontDevice = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .front).devices.first {
  frontInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontDevice)
}

captureSession?.beginConfiguration()
if let front = frontInput, captureSession?.canAddInput(front) == true {
  captureSession?.addInput(front)
}
captureSession?.commitConfiguration()
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution presented by mbuff24.
Array methods include .first(where:) besides .filter()

```
guard let frontCamera = AVCaptureDevice.devices().first(where: { ($0 as AnyObject).position == .front }) as? AVCaptureDevice else {
            fatalError("No front facing camera found")
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation


@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
    var Arrdata:[Studentdata] = []
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
            if let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as? [AVCaptureDevice]
            {
                for device in devices
                {
                    if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo))
                    {
                        if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front)
                        {
                            captureDevice = device
                            if captureDevice != nil
                            {
                                print("Capture device found")
                                beginSession()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


    }

func beginSession()
    {
        do
        {
            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
            stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput)
            {
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        guard let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) else
        {
            print("no preview layer")
            return
        }
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
```