# Accessing front Camera with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-camera, front-camera

I've done some searching and most answers are either in Obj-C or not applicable to this code.

I'm using this guide : http://drivecurrent.com/devops/using-swift-and-avfoundation-to-create-a-custom-camera-view-for-an-ios-app/

and I've got this code from it:

```
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let frontCamera = ????

    var error: NSError?
    var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        input = nil
    }
```

The back camera is the default but I'm not seeing how to straight up access the front camera in order to let people swap back and forth.

Comment: You might want to check out this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155623/how-to-get-the-front-camera-in-swift

Comment: you can use the simple class which can manage the camera session ->  https://github.com/maryamfekri/MFCameraManager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your currently void *frontCamera* has a pretty similar behavior to your *backCamera* one. You need to use `devicesWithMediaType(_ mediaType: String!)` that allows to store in an array all the devices capable of capturing data of type AVMediaTypeVideo.

```
let captureDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice

for device in captureDevices {
    let device = element as! AVCaptureDevice
    if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front {           
        frontCamera = device
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func FromCamera() {
    let imagepicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagepicker.delegate = self
    imagepicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) ? .Camera : .PhotoLibrary
    imagepicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.Front) ? .Front : .Rear
    self.presentViewController(imagepicker, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer is not accepted since it provide complete functionality to capture using front camera.