# Access front camera in Swift 4

Tags: swift, camera, avfoundation

I have this in my camera app

```
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high
camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)

    do {
        let cameraCaptureInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera!)
        cameraCaptureOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

        session.addInput(cameraCaptureInput)
        session.addOutput(cameraCaptureOutput!)

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

How do I access the front camera?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the front camera in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155623/how-to-get-the-front-camera-in-swift)

Comment: I tried to use that before I posted the question and I found much of it to be deprecated so I'm looking for the Swift 4 version if possible.

Comment: @B.Toaster what is the issue or error ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set up your `AVCaptureDevice` this way. Just need to set your default `position` to `front` camera.

```
        var defaultVideoDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

        // Choose the back dual camera if available, otherwise default to a wide angle camera.
        if let dualCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) {
            defaultVideoDevice = dualCameraDevice
        }

        else if let backCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) {
            defaultVideoDevice = backCameraDevice
        }

        else if let frontCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front) {
            defaultVideoDevice = frontCameraDevice
        }

        let videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: defaultVideoDevice!)
```